# How can I let the user share plain text, no hero cards or carousel?

Tags: botframework, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-chatbot

I display quote prices of stocks in one of my bots in the form of text. I would like to let the user be able to share these prices on Messenger without using Hero Cards or generic template. How can I achieve this?

UPDATE 1
How to add share button in persistent menu in addition to this?

Comment: Could you please further explain your use case, your question does not have enough information to help you.

Comment: Would Suggested Actions help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-add-suggested-actions

Answer (score 1):

Text messages can be forwarded by long tapping, then choosing 'forward'. There is no way to add the share button to a text message. Why not just use the generic template without an image?

In the persistent menu, only url and postback buttons are supported.